# Next step to loading Ubuntu on the USB drive after downloading

Tags: system-installation

I am wondering what the next step is to loading Ubuntu on the USB drive after the autorun icon, the "autorun set-up information", and "LOCALE" has been instilled by Rufus into the USB drive. I can't seem to start up the system. I have restarted my computer.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

-LK

Comment: You need to tell the system, i.e., the BIOS or UEFI to boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

When you burn the ISO into the USB flash disk,maybe you should use [bootice](https://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/314000/314773/bootice-01-495x366.png) to do like this:

```
 Choose the `Destination Disk`
`Process MBR` >> Choose one of `UltraISO USB-HDD+/USB-ZIP+` >> install
`Parts Manage` >> Active you device
```

when you start your computer,set your BIOS,select your usb flash disk as the first boot option.save it,restart your PC, you'll see the `System installation interface`.

[download bootice](https://bootice.en.softonic.com/)